# Referencing an Asp.Net Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

**Goal:** I'm trying to add an HTTP endpoint to an existing application for administration / monitoring purposes.

**Setup/Environment:** Both projects are in .Net core and in the same solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.5. The web application is Asp.Net Core 2 and it uses RazorPages for the http front end.

**Reproduction:** This repository contains a simplified version of the solution which demonstrates the problem. https://github.com/crmabs/Referenced-AspNet-Core-2-web-app

By running the project named ConsoleApp from the repo you should get a result like this:

[image: my problem in pixels]

**Question:** How can I properly reference and use an Asp.Net Mvc app with Razor pages into a separate project? I'd like to develop / debug the projects from within VS on a regular way.

Comment: It seems like there is a very similar issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595244/is-it-possible-sensible-to-split-asp-net-core-2-net-framework-web-api-into-cl